# Need help installing a SSL.com certificate on Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-virtual-machine

I just set up an Azure VM. My unsecured website (http) is working fine to this new Azure box. I'm am trying to get the SSL.com certificate working so that https will work, and I'm running into some difficultly. I can't find a document that is straight forward in doing this, and I'm a rookie in setting this up.

I used openssl to convert my .p7b file from SSL.com to a .pbx file that can be imported by Azure. I added it to the Azure Key Vault, and it is visible in the Azure VM. I assigned it to my website in the IIS bindings. But when I go to my website https://www.example.com, it was just timing out.

I tried opening up port 443 on the firewall of the VM, and added an inbound port rule for 443 on the VM, still no luck.

Now, whatever I've done, https://www.example.com logs me into an Azure VM Windows Admin Center webpage.

Does anyone know step by step instructions of what needs to be done?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial available in the official docs for [securing a web server on a Windows virtual machine in Azure with TLS/SSL certificates stored in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server). Each of the steps are backed by detailed PowerShell cmdlets.

The tutorial demonstrates this with a self-signed certificate, but you could also upload an existing, trusted certificate that you already own to Azure Keyvault with the [Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/import-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-4.8.0) cmdlet.